# Pointers of different base types to the same object and unique pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I have an abstract class `Reticule` defined like so:

```
class Reticule : public Drawable, public Object {
    //some irrelevant methods to the question
};
```

It is used for drawing targeting reticules, i.e. if I wanted a spell to have a circle or a conal AoE reticule, I would derive from the above class e.g:

```
class Circle : public Reticule {
public:
    Circle(float radius);

    //etc
};
```

I have another class `World` with 2 methods, one for registering something that is drawable and another that registers objects.

```
class World {
public:
    void registerDrawable(Drawable* drawable);
    void registerObject(Object* object);

    //other irrelevant methods

private:
    std::list<Drawable*> drawables_;
    std::list<Object*> objects_;
};
```

These functions add the pointers to the associated containers. This allows objects in the world to interact with one another.

In my spell I am creating the reticule like so:

```
reticule_ = std::unique_ptr<Recitule>(new Circle(3.0f));
```

My problem is that, how am I meant to register the reticule to my `World` class. It works to do this:

```
world.registerDrawable(&(*reticule_));
world.registerObject(&(*reticule_)));
```

but that doesn't seem right to me as I defined `reticule_` as a unique pointer and I now have 2 more pointers pointing to it, they're just not of type `Reticule*`

Should I not use an `unique_ptr`? Do I change everything to `shared_ptr` but then that doesn't make sense when adding a simple object to the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `unique_ptr` if you want them both to "own" it.  In that case `shared_ptr` is appropriate.

Alternatively you could register the raw pointer.  You would need to be sure to unregister the object before it was destroyed however.  This creates other problems, because throwing within a destructor is a bad thing.

Using `shared_ptr` on simple objects is fine though, and it would be my recommendation unless the profiler tells you that it is a problem.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that, I wasn't sure whether I was allowed the `unique_ptr` because it was of a different type as the other pointers but I guess in the end they're still all pointing to the same object in memory? They just look at that memory differently. Thanks.

Comment: @Lerp Both `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` can be used in a polymorphic fashion.  It probably is doing the downcast explicitly.  The container would be `std::list<std::shared_ptr<Drawable> >` instead of `std::list<Drawable *>`.